# I would like to be able to have a bot automatically update a members username to a specific nickname if the user doesn't already have a nickname

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@Cog.listener()
async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
    n = before.nick
    if n:
        if n.lower().count("★") <= 0:
            await after.edit(nick="NICKNAME")
```

The code above changes the users nickname to "NICKNAME" if the user has attempted to change their nickname without the Star symbol. But I would like to have the bot automatically update their usernames instead and change it to the Star symbol nickname without the users having to manually do it themselves, if they don't already have it in there username to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `on_member_join` event and change the nickname when someone joins a guild

```py
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.edit(nick="NICKNAME")
```

*Note: This will work when someone **joins** a guild, but it will not change the nick of the users that already are in the guild, you could make a simple command for that*

```py
async def whatever(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if not "★" in member.nick: # Or whatever character
            await member.edit(nick="NICKNAME")
```

#### Reference:

- [`on_member_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join)
- [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit)

Comment: Thank you very much, it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the event [on_member_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join) to assign once they join the server. For existing members, you could periodically iterate over [guild.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.members) and adapt all the members where necessary.